# In XSLT, how to copy all attributes from all child nodes to root node of xml?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I want a XSLT program which will transform a XMl  a file in a way that will read/extract all attributes from all child nodes(till deep level ) of root node  and copy to parent node. Then remove all child nodes.
Input xml

```
enter code here
<root>
  <a key="1"/> 
  <b key1="2">
    <c key3="3"/>
  </b>
</root>
```

and output xml would be like this:

```
<root key="1" key1="2" key3="3" />
```

Comment: How do you want to handle child nodes that have the same attribute? (for example if a, b, and c all had an attribute "id" for example which value would you use in the resulting root element?

Comment: Thanks. Yes for initial step. It will not a problem for me. Its ok to come same attribute name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do quite simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="//@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, an element cannot have two attributes with the same name. If your XML has more than one instance of the same attribute, they will overwrite each other and only the last one will be present in the output.